# Android storing string array

Tags: android, string, storage

I've been looking for over the past day and a half at several websites about how to store strings/string arrays/etc. and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not sure if I'm just not quite comprehending how to implement data storage..or what. But here is my problem, simply put, I have two activity pages (we'll name 'A,B' respectively) . All I want to do is get a string from a text view in Activity B, store it in an array, and then have it accessed by clicking a button in Activity A.

I know it is simple, but I hit a block for some reason... I am trying to use SharedPreferences but how would I obtain the string from Activity B, store it in a global array, and let it be accessed by a different activity (Activity A) ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store it into shared preferences (usually in onPause()):

```
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(GAME_STATE, writer.toString());
            editor.commit();
```

in one activity and load in another (usually in onResume()):

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);


    String jsonState = preferences.getString(GAME_STATE, null);
```

And nothing prevents you from using public static variables

Comment: Ok, this is what I've been seeing but the problem for me occurs here. The program is very simple and I am not using any threads, just intents. It seems very inefficient, but it is a very small program. When calling, putString for the editor, how is this being stored? Does the editor act like a stack, able to take on multiple strings? Or can it only store one string at a time?

Comment: preferences editor is map. just dread javadocs on it.  it can store strings and primitives under different keys.  while it may seem ineffective, this is proper way to do in environment where your activity can be stopped and killed at any moment (for example on incoming call)

Comment: If I wanted to store one string it would be easy now, but how would you store multiple strings? If a user presses the "save text" button, then that code would be called, but would it not create a string in editor with the same key? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: then choose different keys.   when U gabe to store a lot of different values, I just serialize them to JSON and store as string (via: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )

Answer (score 1):

You can't store an array directly in shared preferences, but you can store a set.

See [putStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) and [getStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29). You can add all the items from your array to a  [LinkedHashSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (as long as they are unique) if you wish to store them in SharedPreferences. See Konstantin's answer for the general idea on how to use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can obtain and store value in global array but you will loss everything once you close the application. So its better you create a table and store/get values from the table whenever you required.

Here is an example for creating [SQLite example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: Ok, do you think I would need SQLite, though? I am only looking to store, maybe at most, twenty strings.

Comment: @Derek But what if you store and close the application, you will lost everything on re-opening the application again.

Comment: SQLite would be overkill for this.